# How to align numbering item for all location in a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to align the numbering items in my Word document but it seems that I can only change ONE item only.

Currently if I want to apply that to other similar items, I have to use `Copy Formation` tool.

Another inconvinience I have is that this modified alignment is not kept for the next usage i.e. I have to re-align it manually.

I need to make change once and that is applied for all. How can we do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the proper way of adjusting list indents by right clicking on the list item, selecting the **Adjust list indents** option and changing the value of **Number position**.